# Como utilizar Ajax para enviar dados do formulário no formato JSON para API REST em PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, json, api, rest

Preciso enviar dados de um formulário em formato JSON para inserir no banco através de uma API feita com PHP. Pesquisei um pouco e vi que é possível resolver com Ajax porém não estou conseguindo. Segue abaixo meus códigos:

home.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //EVENTO DE CLICAR NO SUBMIT
        $("#send").click(function(e){
            history.pushState(null, null, "?" + $("form[name=\"formulario\"]").serialize())
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api-create.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $("form[name=\"formulario\"]").serialize()
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formulario" method="post">
        <label>Autor: <input type="text" name="autor" value="" required="required"/></label>
        <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" required="required"/></label>
        <label>Titulo: <input type="text" name="titulo" value="" required="required"/></label>
        <label>Resumo: <input type="text" name="resumo" value="" required="required"/></label>
        <label><button type="button" id="send" name="send"/>Send</button></label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

api-create.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Headers: Acess-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type, 
Acess-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$pautor = $data["autor"];
$pemail = $data["email"];
$ptitulo = $data["titulo"];
$presumo = $data["resumo"];

require_once "dbconfig.php";

$query = "INSERT INTO artigo VALUES (default, '$pautor', '$pemail', '$ptitulo', '$presumo')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Insert Query Failed")){
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product Inserted Successfully", "status" => true));    
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Failed Product Not Inserted ", "status" => false));    
}

?>
```

Comment: "*porém não estou conseguindo*", mas o que está acontecendo? Deu algum erro? No JS ou no PHP? A requisição chegou ou não? Ela foi enviada da maneira que você desejava?

Comment: @Woss a requisição não chegou e consequentemente nada foi cadastrado no banco.

Comment: Então acesse as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador e verifique as abas Console e Network para descobrir porque a requisição não foi feita.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você chamar quando o dom tiver sido lido usando o  $(document).ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //EVENTO DE CLICAR NO SUBMIT
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(e){
        history.pushState(null, null, "?" + $("form[name=\"formulario\"]").serialize())
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api-create.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $("form[name=\"formulario\"]").serialize()
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Bem observado..